# supplying values for parameters to function calls within an onPressed callback in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an app with a list of buttons on the same screen. The `onPressed` functions for all the buttons include a call to a particular function, but each with different parameter values, which are determined at run time. My first attempt at this was along the lines of

```
  _MyHomePageState() {
List<int> vals = [1,2];  //in real application these values are computed by earlier code
int v;
for(int i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {
  v=vals[i];
  butns.add(ElevatedButton(
            onPressed:(){ doSomething(v);}, 
            child: Text('$v')));    
}
```

But this does not work - all the buttons use the parameter values supplied for the last button (in this case, 2)

changing the parameter in `doSomething()` to refer to the list of values, rather than the variable `v` does work

```
 _MyHomePageState() {
List<int> vals = [1,2];  //in real application these values are computed by earlier code
int v;
for(int i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {
  v=vals[i];
  butns.add(ElevatedButton(
          onPressed:(){ doSomething(vals[i]);}, 
          child: Text('$v')));    
}
```

Can someone explain why `v` can be used for the Text widget for the buttons' labels but not in the `onPressed()` function?

Comment: Share your code completely so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare v outside of the for.
on pressed gets called after v has been assigned to 2 and this does not save the state of v, it saves only the reference to v;
If you change v over time, the doSomething method gets the currently set value of v.